# How to reduce height of menus in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

If I right click a java project, the menu does not fit into my screen and I cannot select Project properties option for example. It started to happen since version 9, when Oracle abandoned Netbeans and the new authors increased **the height of menu items**.

Compare 8.2 with increased font size to 20, to version 12.5 that I just installed with default font size:
[image]

[image]

Do you know any way to reduce the height of menu items? Or alternatively remove useless items from the project context menu? To reduce menus heights I could remove the items that I am not going to use.

Best regards,
Marian

Comment: [1] I can't reproduce the issue you describe. It would be helpful if you could update your question to include your environment details, and a screen shot that demonstrates the problem. [2] The entries for that context menu vary according to project type (Maven, Ant, C++, etc.), but it is not configurable. What specifically are the _"useless items"_ that you think might be removed from it?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the authors "increased" the size of the fonts, I don't experience your issue (JDK11, Win10). Netbeans has to rely on fonts available on your system.

You can change the font size by editing your `netbeans.conf` file in the `etc` folder in the Netbeans installation directory.

Add `--fontsize 12` (or 14 etc.) in the value of `netbeans_default_options`, and restart Netbeans.